# can't able to add value to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, user-controls

I have a datacontrol.cs(UserControl), which is contain textbox1 and codebehind window having a method with parameter of currentvalue

```
public void bindvalue(float currentvalue)
{
    textbox1.Clear();
    textbox1.Text = currentvalue.ToString();
}
```

I have a Form, Here added the usercontrol in this form and which contains a Button

So when clicking button it pass a currentvalue by the way of method to the datacontrol class like that .

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    float currentvalue = 1500.00f;
    datacontrol  obj = new datacontrol();

    obj.bindvalue(currentvalue);
}
```

Everything working fine to me. It pass the current value to the usercontrol class and there current value assigned/added to the `textbox1.Text = currentvalue.ToString();`. It doesn't shows any error . But finally the textbox doesn't shows any value.

I used breakpoint to check the functionality. It gave current value to the textbox. But strange!!!..
I can't predict whats wrong in my code.
Helps appreciated.:)

Comment: What is `datacontrol`?

Comment: From what I see, you don't do anything with your `obj` except for declaring it, you don't hang it in your forms controls or anything

Comment: Its a usercontrol GUI @BarryO'Kane

Comment: Add instace of `datacontrol` to the form.

Comment: You have to use the instance from your datacontrol not a new object.

Comment: I need to bind value from Form to UserControl textbox @PinBack

Comment: did you add the `datacontrol` by drag and drop in the designer? if so, what is the name of this control in the properties in the designer?

Comment: Yes. its name datacontrol1 @MongZhu

Comment: then your answer is the first part of the post by [Mikhail Neofitov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45143658/5174469)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instance of `datacontrol` with required value (1500.00f) does not exist on your form. You are only delcaring it, passing value and forgetting about it.

If you have already added user control to form and want to call `bindvalue` method of existing control, you should do the following:

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float currentvalue = 1500.00f;
    this.dataControl1.bindvalue(currentvalue);
}
```

Note that `dataControl1` is the name of your user control on the form, it can be different from `dataControl1`.

If you want to create new user control and call `bindvalue`, you should add new instance on the form:

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float currentvalue = 1500.00f;
    datacontrol  obj = new datacontrol();

    obj.bindvalue(currentvalue);
    this.Controls.Add(obj);
}
```

If it is already dynamically added control on the form, declare a field of Form class, assign new instance of it control, when you want it, and call to it as it shows in the first example.

Comment: it adding the controls again

Comment: @User6667769 well, if the control already exists, check the first example code.

Comment: Then dont need to create any instance..?

Comment: @User6667769 instance have already created, when you are declared it.

Comment: @User6667769 look into the YourFormName.Designer.cs file. There will be a line in the section of the autogenerated code : `this.datacontrol1  = new datacontrol();`.  And there also will be a line: `this.Controls.Add(this.datacontrol1 );` This code is generated at the point in time, when you drag and drop the control into your form in the designer

Answer (score 3):

You need add instance of `datacontrol` to the form

```
datacontrol  obj = new datacontrol();
obj.bindvalue(currentvalue);
Controls.Add(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a call to bindvalue method by using the tagename of your user control in button click event handler.
Suppose the tag name is 'datacontrol', then you should use the following lines of code to achieve your task:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float myvalue = 150.50f;
    datacontrol1.BindValue(myvalue);

}
```

Regards, Aamir ( .Net developer)

Please marks this thread as answer if it solved what were looking for... thanks

Comment: "Suppose the tag name is 'datacontrol', then " your code is wrong. Althgou it is just a small detail like a missing 1 but it will make your code not compilable.

Comment: Mong Zhu, how come my code is wrong? I have run this code and the output was ok. This is just a small piece of code.

Comment: please read what you have wrote. "make a call to bindvalue method by using the tagename.... Suppose the tag name is `datacontrol`" you have a typo! because in your code you write:  `datacontrol1.BindValue(myvalue);`. it is indeed a small mistake but a very important one because if the control name is really `datacontrol` then you code will not compile!

Comment: Mong Zhu, i meant the tagname which is created using the following line:<%@ Register src="datacontrol.ascx" tagname="datacontrol" tagprefix="uc1" %>

Comment: where do you use this line? you did not write this in your post.

Comment: this sounds like ASP.NET, but the tag in the question clearly states `winforms`

Comment: o i see, sorry i could not get the clarity of Windows forms. Yes then you are right Mong Zhu. In the case of Windows Form , when the application is compiled, the user control is added in Toolbox and you can drag & drop the control on Form and then pass the value (float in this case) to bindvalue function defined in the UserControl code.